# Create a table using Notion API

Tags: python-3.x, notion-api, notion

I'm trying to figure out how to use Notion API, but following example in their official documentation return an ungooglable error.

I'm following [this docs](https://developers.notion.com/reference/block#table)

and here is my code:

```
headers = {
    'Authorization': f"Bearer {api_key}",
    "accept": "application/json",
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Notion-Version': '2022-02-22'
}

data = {'children': [{'object': 'block',
        'type': 'table',
        'table': {'table_width': 4}}]}

response = requests.patch('https://api.notion.com/v1/blocks/d5e1064a-c6aa-49e2-9f25-4111feac84ca/children', headers=headers, json=data)
```

This returns following error:

```
b'{"object":"error","status":400,"code":"validation_error","message":"body failed validation: body.children[0].table.children should be defined, instead was `undefined`."}'
```

But when I add just a heading everything works fine:

```
data = {'children': [{'object': 'block',
        'type': 'heading_2',
        'heading_2': {'rich_text': [{'type': 'text',
        'text': {'content': 'blah-blah'}}]}}]}
```

I literally google everything possible with my error or examples of the api usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developers.notion.com/reference/block#table-rows

> When creating a table block via the Append block children endpoint, the table must have at least one table_row whose cells array has the same length as the table_width.

fallowing the reference, table attribute should be included **children** with **table_row**. and **table_row** should be included cells array which is same length of **table_width**.

here is my test json object.

```
  "type": "table",
  "table": {
    "table_width": 2,
    "children":[
      {"type": "table_row",
       "table_row": {
         "cells":[
          [
            {
              "type": "text",
              "text": {
                "content": 'test1',
              }
            }],
          [{
            "type": "text",
            "text": {
              "content": 'test2',
            }
          }
        ],
        ]
       }
     }
   ]
  }
}
```

each row is 'table_row', if you want to add multiple row, add 'table_row' with same length of table_width.